# Postgres: password authentication failed for user 'username'

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up a postgres database however I am getting errors in the CLI every time I try to initiate 'psql'. Specifically, it's prompting me to enter in a password for my root/personal username (NOT postgres) then saying "password authentication failed for user". I am also not able to initiate the 'template1' database.

If I switch users with 'psql -U postgres', then I am able to successfully login.

How can I change a password for users OTHER than postgres?

So far I've: gone into the PostgreSQL 11 app, clicked on the username db and attempted to update with '/password' as well as ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD 'new password' to no avail. I've also modified the pg_hba.conf to what's pictured below but that does not work either.

screenshots of errors:

[postgres app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOGSI.png)

[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdmqF.png)

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Lci.png)

Comment: did you reload configuration after change pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file, add the message there to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To switch user try this:

> psql -h localhost -p *portno* -U *username* *dbname*;

To change password of a user

> ALTER USER <*desiredusername*> PASSWORD 'password';